# Auto Increment in ng-repeat object

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

I am taking game info from mlb.com and displaying them using angularjs and ng-repeat directive. an example of the JSON feed is below.

```
{
 "data": {
    "games": {
        "next_day_date": "2017-08-19",
        "modified_date": "2017-08-18T16:57:16Z",
        "month": "08",
        "year": "2017",
        "game": {
            "0": [{
                "away_team_name": "CUBS"

            }, {
                "home_team_name": "INDIANS"

            }],
            "1": [{
                "away_team_name": "CUBS"

            }, {
                "home_team_name": "INDIANS"

            }]
        },
        "day": "18"
    }
}
```

I am only able to display the data properly however, only 1 game. html below

```
<div class="card mb-3" ng-repeat="x in scoreboard" ng-if="$index > 1">
  <div class="card-header" align="center">
   {{x.games.game[0].away_team_name}} ({{x.games.game[0].away_win}}-{{x.games.game[0].away_loss}}) At {{x.games.game[0].home_team_name}} ({{x.games.game[0].home_win}}-{{x.games.game[0].home_loss}})<br>
      <small>{{x.games.game[0].time}}</small>
  </div>
  <div class="card-block"></div>
</div>
```

I do understand [0] refers to the game ID '0' in the json feed, however is there a way to auto increment that number in `{{x.games.game[0].time}}` to loop through all games instead of doing each game individually like below?

```
<div class="card mb-3" ng-repeat="x in scoreboard" ng-if="$index > 1">
  <div class="card-header" align="center">
   {{x.games.game[0].away_team_name}} ({{x.games.game[0].away_win}}-{{x.games.game[0].away_loss}}) At {{x.games.game[0].home_team_name}} ({{x.games.game[0].home_win}}-{{x.games.game[0].home_loss}})<br>
      <small>{{x.games.game[0].time}}</small>
  </div>
  <div class="card-block"></div>
</div>
<div class="card mb-3" ng-repeat="x in scoreboard" ng-if="$index > 1">
  <div class="card-header" align="center">
   {{x.games.game[1].away_team_name}} ({{x.games.game[1].away_win}}-{{x.games.game[1].away_loss}}) At {{x.games.game[1].home_team_name}} ({{x.games.game[1].home_win}}-{{x.games.game[1].home_loss}})<br>
      <small>{{x.games.game[1].time}}</small>
  </div>
  <div class="card-block"></div>
</div>
```

I have tried
    *`{{x.games.game[$index + 1].time}}`* but still return only 1 game

Any insight would be appreciated!

Comment: @Hadi it means start at 'index' 1

Comment: Have you tried to use $index: x.games.game[$index].away_team_name

Comment: `$index + 1` would likely result in an array index out of bounds error on the final iteration.

Comment: You're iterating the `scoreboard` itself! That's why you're only getting one result.

Comment: I believe you want to iterate over `scoreboard.games.game`, is that correct?

Comment: that makes sense @Daniel, and idea how to iterate through each scoreboard?

Comment: @Daniel yes, that is correct!

Comment: then you just need to specify `$index` instead of `0`, like `x.games.game[$index].away_team_name`

Comment: @Daniel i have tried that, but it still only returns one game

Comment: If your scoreboard is exactly the same json that you posted in the question, I believe it should not show any game at all! Because there are only 2 games where their keys (indexes) are 0 and 1 and you have an `ng-if="$index > 1"`

Comment: `scoreboard.games.game` is also an object, not an array, therefore order between games is not guaranteed! What I mean is that it's possible that your first game have an id bigger than 1, and if you only have one game with the id bigger than 1, that would explain why the `ng-repeat` is only showing one game. When iterating over objects with `ng-repeat`, `$index` is the key of the property and not it's index or order.

Comment: there are games numbered 1-12

Comment: I know what I was missing, when iterating over objects with ng-repeat the syntax should be `(key, value) in object`. So instead of `x in scoreboard.games.game` it should be `(key, x) in scoreboard.games.game`, where `$index` would have the same value as `key`. Intuitively I can also explain why it was only returning one time, and it is the same reason as before when you're using `x in scoreboard`. Both `scoreboard` and `scoreboard.games.game` return themselves (only one instance) when used inside `ng-repeat` with the same approach as the one when iterating over an array.

Comment: any idea how to implement this?

Comment: sorry, I just went dinner, as I said you just need to replace `x in scoreboard.games.game` with `(key, x) in scoreboard.games.game`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I adjusted my $scope in the controller from

```
.success(function (data) { $scope.scoreboard = data;}
```

to

```
.success(function (data) {$scope.scoreboard = response.data.games.game;}
```

html now looks like

```
<div class="card mb-3" ng-repeat="x in scoreboard track by $index" ng-if="$index > 1">
  <div class="card-header" align="center">{{x.away_team_name}} </div>
</div>
```

works perfectly

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of problems:

- **An iteration over the wrong object**, the iteration should be made over `scoreboard.games.game` instead of `scoreboard`.
- **The syntax** `x in list` **should only be used in the** `ng-repeat` **to iterate over arrays**, both `scoreboard` and `scoreboard.games.game` are NOT arrays, they're Object literals

The syntax to iterate over Object literals in ng-repeat is `(key, value) in object` as mentioned in [the documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat).

To properly solve this problem we must iterate over the **right object** with the **right syntax**, here is how:

```html
<div class="card mb-3" ng-if="key > 1"
     ng-repeat="(key, game) in scoreboard.games.game">

   <div class="card-header" align="center">
      {{ game.away_team_name }} 
      ({{ game.away_win }}-{{ game.away_loss }}) At 
      {{ game.home_team_name }} 
      ({{ game.home_win }}-{{ game.home_loss }})<br />
      <small>{{ game.time }}</small>
   </div>
   <div class="card-block"></div>
</div>
```